# Memory/Allocation errors when setting ImageButton from Camera Photo

Tags: android, image, android-camera

I am trying to take a photo from the phones camera and place in it in a ImageButton as part of a Profile activity including all users details, and then save the image as shared pref.

If I use the following code the ImageButton simply does not update:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
            // method checks data returned form camera via startActivityForResult
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){@Override
                    public void run() {
                        handler.post(new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                                                            photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                                                takeAndSetPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image set to profile!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }//edn inner run


                        });//end new runnab;e

                    }

                };
                new Thread(runnable).start();

            }//end if result OK     
        }// end onActivity
```

Alternatively the image DOES load if I use this method but I get erros:

> Allocation fail for scaled Bitmap
>   Out Of Memory 01-03 10:13:06.645: E/AndroidRuntime(30163):
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error
>   inflating class

The code is using Uro for phot taken:

```
                    public void run() {
                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                        Uri photoShot = data.getData(); view
                        takeAndSetPhoto.setImageURI(photoShot);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image set to profile!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }//edn inner run
```

All suggestions appreciated.
Cheers
Ciaran

Resizing Image:
When resizing the image:

```
Bitmap photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 100, 100, false);
```

It works fine on the emulator with SD card activated, but crashes on a real device (a tablet 8inch)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I was not resizing image when taken form device phone, passed image to this method before setting to the image view:

```
public Bitmap reSizeImage(Bitmap bitmapImage) {
        // resize bitmap image passed and rerun new one
        Bitmap resizedImage = null;
        float factorH = h / (float) bitmapImage.getHeight();
        float factorW = w / (float) bitmapImage.getWidth();
        float factorToUse = (factorH > factorW) ? factorW : factorH;
        try {
            resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage,
                    (int) (bitmapImage.getWidth() * factorToUse),
                    (int) (bitmapImage.getHeight() * factorToUse), false);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Problem resizing Image @Line 510+");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG,
                "in resixed, value of resized image: "
                        + resizedImage.toString());
        return resizedImage;
    }// end reSize
```